# Autofocus: posicionar o cursor no final do valor

Tags: html

Quando gero um `input` tendo valor setado (`value="teste"`) e defino o `autofocus="true"`, o `autofocus` trás o cursor no começo do conteúdo:

```html
<form>
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="p" value="teste"  autofocus="true"/>
 </div>
</form>
```

Existe uma forma padrão do *html* que seta o cursor no final ?

Comment: Teria que ser mesmo somente utilizando HTML? Com JavaScript/jQuery seria bem simples fazer isso.

Comment: @Leandro gostaria que sim. O mais perto foi `onfocus="this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = 500;"` ou da forma do Diego Vieira, mas achei que houvesse um padrão.

Comment: Esse "perto" utilizando `onfocus=` é na verdade com Javascript, assim como todas as outras respostas. Pessoalmente não me parece que seja possível de fazer somente com html.

Comment: @Isac Sim, por isso ainda não fechei a pergunta, estou na esperança :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A alternativa de solução que conheço **não** é somente com *HTML*, ela utiliza também o *JavaScript*.

Diferente das outras soluções nela manipulo o cursor sem sobreescrever o valor, utilizando o [setSelectionRange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange):

> O `métodoHTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange()` define as posições
>   inicial e final da seleção atual do texto em um elemento `<input>`.

**Exemplo 1:**

```html
<form>
   <div>
  <input type="text" name="p" value="teste"  
  onfocus="this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;"  
  autofocus="true"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Exemplo 2:**

```js
var campo   = document.getElementById("p");
var tamanho = campo.value.length;
campo.setSelectionRange(tamanho, tamanho);
```

```html
<form>
   <div>
 <input type="text" name="p" id="p" value="teste"  autofocus="true"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Obs.:**

Considerando a quantidade possível de dígitos em um `<input />` evite atribuir ao `selectionEnd` um valor constante a menos que você saiba o `maxlength`.

Comment: Acho que entre todas, o mais simples e viável possível seria a primeira, implementando o `this.value.length;` ao invés de um valor fixo.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode armazenar o *value* atual em uma variável temporária, aí setar o valor para vazio, e então setar novamente para a variável temporária.

Exemplo:

```html
<input type="text" name="p" autofocus value="teste" onfocus="var temp=this.value; this.value=''; this.value=temp"/>
```

Comment: É quase o mesmo estilo desse: `onfocus="this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = 500;"`... mas eu achei que houvesse algo padrão...

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="p" autofocus value="teste" onfocus="this.value = this.value;"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Seria isso `onfocus="this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = 500;"` ? Da forma que fez, não funcionou...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.value = this.value;
});
```

```css
.myinput
{
padding: 5px; 
margin:5px;
}
form{
  margin:10px;
  }
  .mysubmit
  {
  float:right;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
   <form>
      First name: <input class="col-sm-12 myinput"type="text" name="p" autofocus value="meu nome"><br>
      <input class="col-sm-3 mysubmit" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

O atributo autofocus é um atributo booleano.

Quando presente, especifica que um elemento  deve obter automaticamente o foco quando a página é carregada.

```
<form>
  First name: <input type="text" name="p" autofocus><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp

Comment: Sim Marcelo, mas quando o input tem um value, eu quero carregar o cursor para o final da palavra. Esse é o problema.

Comment: olha voce pode utilizar um script para empurrar

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que utilizando exclusivamente `html` não seja possível mover o cursor para o final do texto ao focar no `input`, segue solução com `jQuery`:

```js
var input = $("#teste"); 
tmp = input.val(); input.focus().val("").blur().focus().val(tmp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="p" value="teste" id="teste">
</div>
```